# Java Make a PrintWriter write two different Writer's

Tags: java, io

I am refactoring some code and want to make a PrintWriter that will send output to two seperate Writer's (not streams, and they ultimately go different places, one of them may have other stuff sent to it from elsewhere).

For streams there is the Apache TeeOutputStream, is there anything for Writer or will I need to go via a stream and back to text?

Comment: I did the same, a `MultiPrintWriter(Writer superWriter, Writer... otherWriters)`. Did not find a ready one. Only logging may tee (fork) out.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is no such "multiwriter" in the standard Java library, but you can create one very easily. The reason for "easily" is because there are only 3 `abstract` methods in `java.io.Writer`: `close()`, `flush()` and `write(char[] cbuf, int off, int len)`.

The default implementation of all other overloads of the `write()` method call this abstract one.

You just have to store the writers you want to forward to and do just that: forward the calls of these 3 abstract methods:

```
class MultiWriter extends Writer {

    private final Writer[] writers;

    public MultiWriter(Writer... writers) {
        this.writers = writers;
    }

    @Override
    public void write(char[] cbuf, int off, int len) throws IOException {
        for (Writer w : writers)
            w.write(cbuf, off, len);
    }

    @Override
    public void flush() throws IOException {
        for (Writer w : writers)
            w.flush();
    }

    @Override
    public void close() throws IOException {
        for (Writer w : writers)
            w.close();
    }

};
```

**Note:**

I know you wanted a `PrintWriter`, but since our `MultiWriter` is a `java.io.Writer`, you can simply pass it to a `PrintWriter` like this:

```
PrintWriter pw = new PrintWriter(new MultiWriter(writer1, writer2));
```

**Note #2:**

In my implementation I did not catch exceptions thrown by the writers we forward to. If for example the `write()` method of a "child" writer would thow an `IOException`, even if we would succeed to write to other writers, the one that failed will still be failed... If we wanted to handle individual exceptions, we would have to implement a new `IOException` that could hold a collection of other `IOException` because multiple "child" writers could fail just as easily.

Comment: And none in the apache commons stuff either (like the stream one)?

Answer (score 0):

It's not hard to implement this yourself. The Writer-Interface has just a handful of abstract methods. So something like this should do:

```
public class TeeWriter implements Writer {

private Writer w1, w2;

...

public void write(char[] cbuf, int off, int len) throws IOException {
    IOException pending = null;
    try {
        w1.write(cbuf, off, len);
    } catch(IOException e){
        pending = e;
    }
    try {
        w2.write(cbuf, off, len);
    } catch(IOException e) {
        if(null==pending) {
            throw new IOException("Writing to w2 failed", e);
        } else {
            // unfortunately the error message for w1 is lost here, so maybe you can e.g. log it or append it to the string in the new one
            throw new IOException("Writing to w1 and w2 failed", e);
        }
    }
    if(null!=pending) {
        throw new IOException("Writing to w1 failed", e);
    }
}

...

}
```

The other methods will be similiar.

Answer (score 0):

Yes. (I need to type 30 characters at least)

https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-io/apidocs/org/apache/commons/io/output/TeeWriter.html