# Java: write to multiple files using a BufferedWriter array (or another way?)

Tags: java, arrays, file

Instead of having 15 BufferedWriters, is there a way that I could write to 15 different files using an array?

```
public static void main (String [] args) {
    try {
        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("" ));
        BufferedWriter bw = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter( "1occurrence.txt"));

        HashMap<String,Integer> hash = new HashMap<String,Integer>();


 while ((line= br.readLine() ) != null) {

    if ( !hash.containsKey(genesym)) {
                hash.put (genesym, 1);
                int count=0;
                bw.write(line + "\n");
            }

            else  {
                count = hash.get(genesym);
                if (count==1) {
                    bw2.write(line + "\n");
                    count++;
                }
                else if (count==2) {
                    bw3.write(line + "\n");
                    count++;
                }
```

Then I have 12 more 'else if' statements to write to up to 15 different files.
Something like

```
BufferedWriter [] bw = new BufferedWriter[15];

for (int i=0; i<15; i++) {

    array[i] = new BufferedWriter(); }
```

I realize this syntax is highly incorrect, but this is the best way I can explain it.

Thanks for the help!

Comment: Sounds like what you want is a MultiWriter. Check out this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25382876/java-make-a-printwriter-write-two-different-writers

Answer (score 2):

I do not understand why there is a need to a create `BufferedWriter` array.

If your requirement is to write to 15 different files then you can have array of 15 file names and change the reference of `BufferedWriter` in each iteration:

```
String[] fileNames = {"file1.txt","file2.txt",....} // 15 file names;    
BufferedWriter writer = null;
for(int i=0;i<fileNames.length;i++)
{
   writer = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter(fileNames[i]));
   writer.wrtier(data); // write data to file
}
```